# Develop Application like Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Develop application like Google play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839912/develop-application-like-google-play)

I want to develop application like "Google play" to my organization purpose. Please give me some advice on this ? How do i start this?

I am looking for we have the server which has contains android application. By using this application it has to list out all the application available from our server and also listed the application which is installed from our server and show the updates for installed application if its available in our server.

Comment: that question get closed

Comment: but you are not supposed to duplicate your question. If it got closed then it is inappropriate in some context.

Comment: So what makes you think that you have improved the question enough for it not to be closed again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing app is quite easy - just send intent to "open" .apk file.
Listing installed application also possible - PackageManager
Checking for updates - GCM or AlarmManager frequently checking for updates.

On the other hand, maybe all you need is private channel introduced last time:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494992

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use Google play itself for that purpose. Take a look here:

http://googleenterprise.blogspot.ca/2012/12/a-new-way-to-distribute-your-internal.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be a bit more specific? You need here both a server and client side component, maybe use some rest web-services to feed your client. As a quick idea you can just put out a gridview with some custom items which while scrolling would async call your web-service to display your apps.

Again, I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, try to be a bit more specific.